# IRB and Ruby Object Model

Tags: ruby, oop

I am a beginner at Ruby who is trying to understand its Object Model.

In IRB. I created a class called  `MyClass` and started to check the Object Model like so:

```
    2.1.0p0 :013 > MyClass.class
     => Class
    2.1.0p0 :014 > MyClass.superclass
     => Object 
    2.1.0p0 :015 > Class.class
     => Class 
    2.1.0p0 :016 > Class.superclass
     => Module 
    2.1.0p0 :017 > Object.class
     => Class 
    2.1.0p0 :018 > Object.superclass
     => BasicObject 
    2.1.0p0 :019 > BasicObject.class
     => Class 
    2.1.0p0 :020 > BasicObject.superclass
     => nil
```

#### Question 1

Why do `Myclass.superclass` and `Class.superclass` are different when `MyClass.class == Class.class` returns `true`?

```
    2.1.0p0 :021 > Class.class == MyClass.class
     => true
```

In other words: Why are their superclasses different?

#### Question 2

Is this diagram accurate?
[Diagram's Link](http://whitequark.org/images/static-ruby/ruby-eigenclass.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045195/understanding-ruby-class-and-ancestors-methods/19045339#19045339 to understand object model..

Comment: @ArupRakshit There is the best explanation on the subject so far. Thank you sir.

Comment: You can show these relationships easily with [Module#ancestors](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors): `MyClass.ancestors
 => [MyClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`,  
`Class.ancestors
 => [Class, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]`.

Comment: I always found this really helpful: http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Ruby classes al also objects, that's why the class of a class is actually `Class`.

That explains why:

```
Class.class   #=> Class
MyClass.class #=> Class
Class.class == MyClass.class #=> true
```

You are not calling `class` over an instance of each class but calling it over the classes itself. Is almost the same as:

```
"hey".class  #=> String
"jude".class #=> String
"hey".class == "jude".class #=> true
```

Here is what you were probably expecting at the beginning:

```
MyClass.new.class #=> MyClass
Class.new.class   #=> Class
MyClass.new.class == Class.new.class #=> false
```