# Why does 'class' show 'Class' when 'ancestors.include? Class' is 'false'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class `User` that inherits from ApplicationRecord. When I check `User.ancestors.include?(Class)`, the result is `false` but for `User.class`, the result is `Class`.

What's the use case for the information supplied by the `class` method in such cases? What does it really tell me to be of practical use? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the use case for the information supplied by the class method in such cases? What does it really tell me to be of practical use? It doesn't seem to have anything to do with inheritance.

`class` works the same way for every object. Calling `class` on a class provides the same information as calling `class` on an instance. That's because in Ruby, classes are instances, too.

`'foo'.class` returns `String` because `'foo'` is an instance of `String`. Likewise, `User.class` returns `Class` because `User` is an instance of `Class`.

In particular, `User` is *not* an instance of `ApplicationRecord`.

It might not be obvious that `User` is an instance of `Class` when  creating it via the [`class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Defining+a+class) keyword:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord; end
```

But it becomes very obvious when you create it explicitly via [`Class.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Class.html#method-c-new): (both examples produce the same result)

```
User = Class.new(ApplicationRecord)
User.class #=> Class
```

Because the above is just like: (using `String.new` for demonstration purposes)

```
foo = String.new('foo')
foo.class #=> String
```

Answer (score 2):

`User` is a class. All classes are instances of the class `Class` (i.e., `User.class #=> Class`). Therefore, all instance methods defined on `Class`, or on `Class`'s ancestors, can be invoked on `User` (i.e., every instance method of `Class` is a class method of `User`).

For example, one of `Class`'s instance methods is `instance_methods`. One can therefore execute `User.instance_methods` to obtain an array of `User`'s instance methods.

Answer (score 1):

> Classes in Ruby are first-class objects—each is an instance of class
>   `Class`

`User` is an **object** of class `Class` (which inherits from `Object`). 
[class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-class) is an instance method of `Object`. It returns the class of the object. Therefore, `User.class` returns `Class`. Every object will have this method, and it is useful to know what the object is (e.g., for debugging). Consider this code:

```
1.class
# => Fixnum
"q".class
# => String
```

The reason why `User.ancestors` does not return `Class` is because it returns the modules included in the `module`. For example, `Class.ancestors` will include `Class`, but not `User` because `User` is an object of `Class`, which includes its own modules.

Comment: I have restored the question in its original form. Editor had removed the reference to ApplicationRecord. I guess source of my question is: If User class inherits from ApplicationRecord, why is it (ApplicationRcord) not its class?

Comment: Moti, I am unclear about what you mean by Name.ancestors. What is Name?

Comment: `User` is an object of type `Class` thus `User.class` is `Class` as literal `1` is an object of type `Fixnum`. If you run `User.ancestors` you should see `ApplicationRecord` among them

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i meant `User` i edited my answer and comment. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: You answer is very nice the main confusion point is to remember that a Class definition is also an object. And clarify where the methods such as `class` (`Object`) and `ancestors` (`Module` class) come form

Answer (score 1):

After reading another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045195/understanding-ruby-class-and-ancestors-methods), I realized that it can only be understood by keeping the following in mind:

1. `User` class has a double role. It plays Class as well as Object.

   - As Class, it lets other classes inherit from it.
   - As Object, it inherits the class method all the way up from the Object class.
2. If I wanted my `User.class` to behave on the traditional lines (that is, `User.class` shows `ApplicationRecord`), then I have to override
   it as follows:

   `class User
     def self.class
       self.superclass
     end
   end`

Comment: `'foo'.class` returns `String` because `'foo'` is an instance of `String`. Why should `User.class` return `ApplicationRecord`? Obviously, `User` is not an instance of `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: Because it is an object and it inherits from ApplicationRecord. Doesn't that amount to anything?

Comment: But that's not what `class` is for. `class` returns the class an object has been instantiated from (instantiated != inherited). `User` is an instance of `Class`. It therefore responds to the instance methods of `Class`, like [`superclass`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Class.html#method-i-superclass). It does not respond to the instance methods of `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to get my head around. What is the use case for an instance that does not inherit? It will be a great help if you can explain that.

Comment: What do you mean by _"an instance that does not inherit"_?